# Drop Down Menu - With Parent Nav Button IN Hover State

Tags: html, css, hover, drop-down-menu

I am working with www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/index.php

The **Entertainment** link has a drop down menu, and I am trying to make it so that the drop down hovers still keep the **Entertainment** parent link to be in its hover state. (Does that make sense?) Also, this will be a double drop down in the near future.

My CSS :

```
#nav ul li:hover ul#sub li a {
display:block;
background:#e6e6e6;
color:#CC0066;
padding:5px 15px 0px 25px;
height:25px;
width:290px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
border-right: none;
margin: 0 0;

}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="nav-box">
    <div id="main-nav">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="company"><a title="Company" href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/company.php"></a></li>
                <li id="entertainment"><a title="Entertainment" href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/entertainment.php"></a>
                    <ul id="sub">
                    <li id="dance"> <a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/guitarist-original-music.asp">Dance</a></li>
                        <ul id="subDance">
                            <li id="smiths"> <a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/guitarist-original-music.asp">Smiths</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li id="classicRock"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/guitarist-shows-covers.asp">Classic Rock | Top 40 | Rock</a></li>
                    <li id="country"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/commercial-tv-film-jingles.asp">Country</a></li>
                    <li id="rockabilly"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/composer.asp">Rockabilly | Reggae | Bluegrass | Other</a></li>
                    <li id="karaoke"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/composer.asp">Karaoke | Live Band Karaoke | All Requests</a></li>
                    <li id="solos"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/composer.asp">Solo's | Duo's | Trio's</a></li>
                    <li id="productionShows"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/composer.asp">Production Shows</a></li>
                    <li id="dj"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/composer.asp">DJ's</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="video"><a href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/video.php"></a>
                </li>
                <li id="studio"><a href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/studio.php"></a>
                </li>
                <li id="liveAudio"><a href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/live-audio.php"></a>
                </li>
                <li id="eventPlanning"><a href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/event-planning.php"></a>
                </li>
                <li id="contact"><a href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/contact.php"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end Nav -->
    </div> <!-- end Main Nav -->
</div> <!-- end Nav Box -->

#nav ul li:hover ul#sub li a:hover {
background:#CCC;
color:#CC0066;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to make it so that the drop down hovers still keep the
>   Entertainment parent link to be in its hover state.

Change the selector here:

```
#nav #entertainment a:hover {
    background-position:0 -20px;
}
```

into this:

```
#nav #entertainment:hover > a
```

That means: whenever the element with an `id` of `entertainment` (that's inside an element with the `id` of `nav`) is hovered over, select any `a` elements that are [direct children](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector).

You'll have to make the "same change" for each of your other buttons.

---

It's not optimal to use `#nav #entertainment ..` - it's an "overly qualified selector" (two `id`s).

`#entertainment ..` is sufficient.

See: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

It doesn't make any practical difference - but, it is a best practise that you should try to adhere to.

Comment: Thank You Sir, You always pull through. I will read your provided material. Thanks Again.